# Where to find geard deployment fixture/config documentation?

Tags: docker

I can't seem to find any good documentation on geard. Specifically, I'd like to understand the format of the json deployment fixture/configuration file. There are a bunch of examples of sample json deployment fixtures at https://github.com/openshift/geard/tree/master/deployment/fixtures. But now where that I can find that explains what is expected.

(And yes, I have googled.)

Comment: The docker repository notes wasn't helpful? https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/openshift/geard/  it shows expected input for the geard docker image.

Comment: That page references using one of the fixtures I mentioned above. But, does nothing to document the format of the fixtures.